# Excel Macro, Sending user's data

Tags: excel, vba, macros

So I am currently studying SQL Server but right now I am just working a standard office admin job while I'm studying. 
I never really made macro's before and little knowledge on VB but decided to design a macro for work to make things a bit easier for my team.
The macro just very simply allows the user to enter data, stats etc and gives the percentage or average statistic resulting in a total letting the user know if the statistics have been hit that day, week, month etc.
It works well but I would like to add a "SUBMIT" button that when a user clicked it would send the data they have entered in specified cells to myself. I am not sure how to go about it, If needed I don't have access to systems like SQL, Visual Studio etc in work as said just basic admin job at the moment.

Would It need to be submitted as a CSV? or could it be submitted from the user's sheet straight onto another macro I have designed giving the results for the whole team? As said I am totally new to this idea.

Cheers Guys.

Comment: When you say that you want to send data to yourself your talking about a mail with the excel book as an attachment ?

Comment: No what I mean is just extracting the data only, if possible of course. So if I had "macro_user" which my team is using and I had myself "macro_owner" I would like the data the user entered into "macro_user" to be passed to "macro_owner" displaying the data on the sheet, then with some calculated cells displaying the teams statistics as a whole.

Comment: You mean like a sheet for them to enter data, and a locked sheet for you to get a copy of the values they enter ?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, so data they enter in say cells A1-A10 & B1-B10 is all passed onto my sheet when they click a submit button.

Comment: Ok, check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awright, according to what you may need in a very simple approach, the first thing you need to do it's to know the cells where they're going to enter info (care with ranges ), let's assume for this example that whe only had one data entered in the first cell of the team worksheet. So, create a button called 'button1' or as you wish and on the click event use this code :

```
Private Sub button1_click()

Teamsheet.Cells(row,column) = Yoursheet.Cells(destinyrow,destinycolumn)

End Sub
```

That would copy the value from one sheet to another, now, if you had you sheet locked via password, you must unlock it before doing that,then lock it again so code would be like this :

```
Private Sub button1_click()

  On Error Resume Next
    yoursheet.unprotect password:="yourpassword"
    Teamsheet.Cells(row,column) = Yoursheet.Cells(destinyrow,destinycolumn)
  On Error Resume Next
    yoursheet.PROTECT password:="yourpassword"

End Sub
```

I clarify that this is a very simple approach, so, if you're using specific cells you can copy one by one and this would do (so you can make anny calculation son your admin sheet), but when you're copying ranges should be like this :

```
Teamsheet.Range("A1:D3").Value = yoursheet.Range("A1:D3").Value
```

Also, always consider how they enter this data you need.

UPDATE :

Let's say you have a team workbook and yours is admin_workbook, concept it's similar. This code will do what you need but both workbooks should be at the same folder or path :

```
Private Sub button1_click()
   Var_data = Teamsheet.Cells(row,column)
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\admin_workbook.xls"
   ThisWorkbook.Activate
   Admin_sheet.Cells(destinyrow,destinycolumn) = var_data
   Workbooks("admin_workbook.xls").Close SaveChanges:=True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

First you capture data on a var, then you open your admin book, put the data on the cell you want and close that workbook saving changes (you decide if you keep this line or mantain the workbook open and save manually). Also, Application.screenupdating it's a line that helps your screen doesn't flick when changing between workbooks.

Hope it helps friend !

Comment: thanks really appreciate it, I think I forgot to mention that they are different saved macro enabled files though? Is it still possible with this code?

Comment: @JonathanClark I see, of course, but it requires come changes. Check the update i did to the answer, and remember to mark it as correct if it solved your requirement.